# Complex Conjugation Proof

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

Hello the question is: 1. Prove (z*)^n = (z^n)* where * represents the complex conjugate.
This is my proof https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scnp7.jpg . I looked online to verify if my proof was right, but all the ones i come across use induction. I'm assuming my proof is wrong i just cant tell where or why its wrong. If someone could let me know why it is that would be great. Thank you!

Comment: The proof will be more clear if you introduce and define the mathematical quantities that you refer to in the proof, specifically $x, y$ and $t$.

Comment: Your proof relies on de Moivre's Theorem $(\cos t +i\sin t)^n=\cos nt +i\sin nt$ for   $n\in \mathbb N.$  From an axiomatic view-point, we can give a 
 definition of  $z^n$ for any given $n\in \mathbb N$ that you care to specify, but to give a single sentence that  defines $z^n$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$,  we need a def'n of $\mathbb N$ that must include the property of Induction. So you can't really avoid induction and still  prove de Moivre's Theorem. But there's nothing  wrong with using it to prove $\overline {z^n}=(\bar z)^n.$

Comment: Go to the Help Center on this site and click on "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?" and follow the links.... BTW the usual notation for the  complex conjugate of $z$ is $\bar z$.

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit I don't understand what the idea of your proof is. Maybe you should write out the proof in Mathjax, with running commentary, if you want feedback on that. The way I see it, we first check (direct computation) that $\overline{z_1z_2} = \overline{z_1}\overline{z_2}$ for all $z_1, _2 \in \mathbb{C}$. From this we prove the result by induction in a standard way, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

$$
z^n=|z|^ne^{in\theta}\\
(z^n)^*=|z|^ne^{-in\theta}\\
{z^*}^n=|z|^ne^{-in\theta}
$$

Q.E.D